# Does Goloka have any scriptural interpretation in yoga parlance?

Tags: krishna, yoga, goloka

Goloka is a place where Radha and Krishna reside. It is mentioned across many scriptures.

Is there any interpretation of Goloka in yoga?

Comment: Goloka is a development in the puranas. I assume when you say 'yoga', you are referring to the philosophical school, which is older than the puranas, so no reference to Goloka.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Nobody refers to a particular philosophical school when they talk about Yoga. In Hinduism the word has a much much broader usage. Here asker is talking about whether there is a yogic interpretation of Goloka like there is for Kailash (which is usually interpreted as Sahsrara) and Kashi (which is the Avimukta Ksetra or Ajna Chakra) etc.

Comment: There was already a question existing on this subject.  Please go through it.  It may give clue about Goloka.(https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28841)